# Date Format Switched Passing Parameter From Jquery to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the following in my view:

```
   var myDate = $(inpDateCompleted).val();

   alert(myDate)
   var url = '@(Url.Action("HoursByDay", "DashBoard"))?dateCompleted=' + myDate;
   alert(url)
```

Both alerts correctly display the date format as 01/11/2011 (1st of November).  However once the date is passed into in my controller event via the above url the date is incorrect as 11/01/2011(11th of January):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult HoursByDay(DateTime dateCompleted)
{       
     var s = ExecuteSqlCommand2(dateCompleted);            
    return Content(s, "application/json");
}
```

And the data produced is incorrect.  How can I correct this?

As per recommendations I have set the culture using:

```
        var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            // Set options here to change middleware behavior
            SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-NZ"),     
            },
            SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-NZ"),      
            }
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions, defaultRequestCulture: new RequestCulture("en-NZ"));
```

Comment: Have you set the culture in the server to one that accepts `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: The server date is set to `d/MM/yyyy` in the control panel.

Comment: You may need to use a framework like 'moment.js' to interpret the date on the client side once its retrieved from the form control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know your date string will be always in the `dd/MM/yyyy` format, you may use the `DateTime.TryParseExact` method to build a datetime object from a string. Change your Action method parameter to a string and parse this string with the pattern/format.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult HoursByDay(string dateCompleted)
{       

   DateTime parsedDate;

   if(DateTime.TryParseExact(dateCompleted,"dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                             DateTimeStyles.None,out parsedDate))
   {
     // parsedDate is a valid DateTime object now
     var s = ExecuteSqlCommand2(parsedDate);            
     return Json(s);
   }
   else
   {
      // could not create a valid DateTime object from inputString
      // to do  :return something
   }
}
```